# Why is there a syntax error occuring

Tags: java, syntax-error

```
// The "Summative" class.
// Melanie Deivendram
// Jan.16,2012
// Purpose: To create a program as part of the summative
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;

public class Summative

    static Console c;           // The output console

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        c = new Console ();

        // Title Page 

        c.setColor (Color.orange);
        c.fillRect (0, 0, 2000, 900);
        c.drawRect (0, 0, 2000, 900);

        c.setColor (Color.white);
        Font times = new Font ("Times", Font.BOLD, 50);
        c.setFont(times);
        c.drawString ("Summative", 180, 50);

        Font tahoma = new Font ("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20);
        c.setFont(tahoma);

        c.getChar ();
        c.clear ();       

        int choice;

        {
        c.drawString ("\t\t 1.Count Vowels", 0, 250);
        c.drawString ("\t\t 2.One Dimensional Array Task", 0, 300);
        c.drawString ("\t\t 3.Graphical animation", 0, 350);
        c.drawString ("\t\t 4.String Methods", 0, 400);
        c.drawString ("\t\t 5.ICS3U Program Portfolio ", 0, 450);
        c.drawString ("\t\t 6.Exit", 0, 490);

        }


       do
        {
        c.print ("What is your choice (1-6): ");
        choice = c.readInt ();
        if ((choice < 1) || (choice > 6))
        c.println ("Invalid ... enter 1-6 only");
        }
        while ((choice < 1) || (choice > 6));
        switch (choice)
        {

        }
        }
         if (choice==1)

         {

        c.println ("What word would you like to enter?");

    String word = c.readString ();

    int count1 = 0;
      for (int num = 0 ; num < word.length () ; num++)
      {
        char numbers = word.charAt (num);
        if (numbers == '0' || numbers == '1' || numbers == '2' || numbers == '3' || numbers == '4' || numbers == '5' || numbers == '6' || numbers == '7' || numbers == '8' || numbers == '9')
        {
          count1++;
        }
      }

      if (count1 != 0)

      {
      c.println("That is invalid, please try again");
      }

     if (count1 == 0)
  {

    int count = 0;
      for (int num = 0 ; num < word.length () ; num++)
      {
        char vow = word.charAt (num);
        if (vow == 'a' || vow == 'e' || vow == 'i' || vow == 'o' || vow == 'u' || vow == 'A' || vow == 'E' || vow == 'I' || vow == 'O' || vow == 'U')
        {
          count++;
        }
      }
      c.println (" There are " + count + " vowels");

      if (count == 0)

      {
      c.println("There are no vowels in the word");
      }

  }
```

This is my exam project and there seems to be a syntax error when i run the program. The error occurs on line 8 and 9 the one with the class and the one under it. What i was doing here was a menu and those were the options. I use "Ready to program" in order to create programs.

Comment: "syntax error when i run the program" - Syntax errors happen when **compiling**, not running the program. Does the program compile? If not, then what error message does the compiler give you?

Comment: you are look like missing "{" just after public class Summative. just for future reference try to select the line where suggest the error e.g. in this case line 8 as it is not clear from your question where is line 8.

Answer (score 3):

Your missing `{`:

```
public class Summative {

    static Console c;
```

**EDIT**

As mentioned by @ccheneson the closing `}` for your class definition seems to be missing as well.

You should have a look at your code indention, which seems to be good at the start, but fails later on. With proper indention you can easily spot those errors as almost any indented block has to be enclosed by `{` and `}`.